# I am getting an error "Error generating the report: java.lang.NullPointerException" while running the JMeter script using JMeter-Maven plugin

Tags: jmeter, pom.xml, jmeter-5.0, jmeter-maven-plugin

I am getting an error "Error generating the report: java.lang.NullPointerException" while running the JMeter script using JMeter-Maven plugin.

Below is the screen shot of the error I am getting:
[image: Error Image]

**Below is my pom.xml file:**

http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    4.0.0
    com.branch.performance
    simplifiedAccess
    0.0.1-SNAPSHOT

```
<properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <!--Access Portal Login page URL -->
    <AccessLoginPageURL>test-login.com</AccessLoginPageURL>
    <!-- base URL -->
    <BaseURL>test.branch.com</BaseURL>
    <!-- Number of users to simulate to execute the performance test plan -->
    <numberOfUsers>3</numberOfUsers>
    <!-- Time in seconds to get all users activated -->
    <rampupTimeInSeconds>1</rampupTimeInSeconds>
    <!-- Number of times the plan executed by every user -->
    <numberOfLoops>1</numberOfLoops>
    <apdexSatisfiedThreshold>2000</apdexSatisfiedThreshold>
    <apdexToleratedThreshold>4000</apdexToleratedThreshold>
    <!-- JMeter Dashboard output file report name -->
    <jmeterReportTitle>Performance Dashboard</jmeterReportTitle>
</properties>


<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.lazerycode.jmeter</groupId>
            <artifactId>jmeter-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>


            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>configuration</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>configure</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>jmeter-tests</id>
                    <phase>verify</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>jmeter</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>jmeter-check-results</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>results</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>

            <configuration>
                    <junitLibraries>
                        <artifact>mysql:mysql-connector-java:8.0.18</artifact>
                    </junitLibraries>
                <testFilesIncluded>

                    <jMeterTestFile>MyTestFile.jmx</jMeterTestFile>
                </testFilesIncluded>
                <testResultsTimestamp>false</testResultsTimestamp>
                <propertiesUser>
                    <AccessLoginPageURL>${LoginPageURL}</AccessLoginPageURL>
                    <BaseURL>${BaseURL}</BaseURL>
                    <numberOfUsers>${numberOfUsers}</numberOfUsers>
                    <rampupTimeInSeconds>${rampupTimeInSeconds}</rampupTimeInSeconds>
                    <numberOfLoops>${numberOfLoops}</numberOfLoops>
                    <jmeter.reportgenerator.apdex_satisfied_threshold>${apdexSatisfiedThreshold}</jmeter.reportgenerator.apdex_satisfied_threshold>
                    <jmeter.reportgenerator.apdex_tolerated_threshold>${apdexToleratedThreshold}</jmeter.reportgenerator.apdex_tolerated_threshold>
                    <jmeter.reportgenerator.report_title>${jmeterReportTitle}</jmeter.reportgenerator.report_title>
                    <!-- if below is true then doesn't show summary of events in console log -->
                    <summariser.ignore_transaction_controller_sample_result>false</summariser.ignore_transaction_controller_sample_result>
                    <jmeter.save.saveservice.subresults>true</jmeter.save.saveservice.subresults>
                    <!-- Generate JMeter report with only transaction labels and data without sub samplers -->
                    <!--jmeter.reportgenerator.exporter.html.show_controllers_only>true</jmeter.reportgenerator.exporter.html.show_controllers_only-->                      
                </propertiesUser>
                <generateReports>true</generateReports>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
<reporting>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-report-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0-M4</version>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</reporting>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your test didn't execute successfully:

[image]

therefore results file is empty therefore JMeter fails to generate the [HTML Reporting Dashboard](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html).

Actually a not-properly-handled [NPE](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/NullPointerException.html) indicates that a big problem in the code as yoiu shouldn't normally see issues like this in more or less mature software so you can report the issue via [JMeter Bugzilla](https://jmeter.apache.org/issues.html) as JMeter shouldn't throw a NPE, it should rather report a human-readable message that the results file is empty suggesting [inspecting jmeter.log file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging) for possible reasons.

**So you should see *your_test_script_name.jmx.log* file under `target/jmeter/logs` folder.**, I'm pretty much sure that you will find the root cause of your test script failure there.

Check out [How to Use the JMeter Maven Plugin](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeter-maven-plugin/) article for more information on running JMeter tests via Apache Maven

Comment: Hi Dmitri, Thanks for your reply!! I got the issue resolved as I messed up with the csv file path..

Answer (score 1):

Run the test from GUI Mode once and confirm that test is getting executed properly. then run from the CLI Mode.